# latest length, latitude and position on openstreetmap

Tags: position, latitude-longitude, openstreetmap

I need to show my latest position and length, latitude on OpenStreetMap like this link, http://tools.geofabrik.de/map/#10/54.5536/9.3658&type=Geofabrik_Standard&mlat=54.50582&mlon=9.23807

someone who coded it or have a guide for this?

Comment: Please provide a few more details. Do you just want to show a marker at a specific position? If yes then take a look at Leaflet or OpenLayers.

Comment: I want to show my latest position on map, with a marker and length, latitude, like this link  http://www.gorissen.info/Pierre/maps/googleMapLocationv3.php?zoom=18&lat=55.50266&lon=9.45654&layers=B0000TT

Comment: This site states "Based on code taken from these openlayers examples" which is one of the two tools mentioned in my previous comment.